# Does `build_packages` download all libraries again in the case of a failed build?

Tags: compiling, chroot, chromium-os

I have been trying to set up and build an image of the Chromium OS from the instructions [available here](http://www.chromium.org/chromium-os/developer-guide). My laptop was running the `build_packages` script for about 7-8 hours after which it failed on one package.

Now, my question is:

- Does the build instruction download all the libraries again? I reran the build instruction today, and it kept reading the downloaded packages, marking them invalid, deleting them and then re-downloading.
- The build instruction is getting stuck after a few packages every time. Now, my connection is working correctly, and I synced with the repository yesterday, so why is it failing to download packages?
- How do I figure out the total progress of the build instruction since the text feedback seems to be fragmented and localised to the package being downloaded and built and not the overall build?

---

[Here is the latest failed build log](http://pastebin.com/rPtRqpT6).

Answer (score 1):

If you have re-synced your repo since the initial `./build_packages` was run, then many of the packages will need re-downloading to the updated version. Else, any that were successfully downloaded will be pulled from cache, so long as you didn't choose to delete the cache after a failed build.

If you keep getting stuck on just a few packages after multiple attempts without any variation, then you may need to instead sync with the "full layout" as opposed to the "minilayout". This has resolved such a circumstance in my case. Keep in mind, that this will need to download approximately 12GB vs the 2GB you have downloaded so far for the mini.

For the total progress of the packages build, it does show some progress as you've said of the per package progress, but also it will show you `(x / y pending)` related to packages. While this doesn't give an exact time estimate, it will at least let you know if you are failing in the same place each time or approximate how much longer based on the elapsed time divided by packages downloaded already.