# How to compile Chromium OS

Tags: compiling, chromium-os

I know that there is [this guide](http://www.chromium.org/chromium-os/developer-guide), but every time I tried to compile Chromium OS I never finished.

I need some clear instructions to compile Chromium OS project and install it on my machine.

There is an abandoned project on GitHub, here: https://github.com/dz0ny/lightdm-login-chromeos

Comment: I was in the same situation. I tried [quite a few times](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/91843/29295); it never completed successfully after which I dropped it.

Comment: @AsheeshR Me too... :-(